# \hrule length inconsistent

Tags: rules, tufte, lengths, line

I'm using the `tufte-book` document class. When I use `\hrule`, sometimes it extends the text width (which I want), and other times it extends the full page width, apparently randomly.

How can I get it to remain the text width length consistently between uses? Thanks!

Comment: `\hrule` consistently makes a rule of the width of the current vertical box. If you are getting different widths then code you have not shown is changing the width of the text blocks but if you show no example document impossible to guess what code you have used. Make a small but complete example document with rules of different widths, then someone will debug it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace

```
\hrule
```

with

```
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
```

This will set the width of the rule to the text length, which will be consistent between uses (unless something changes the width of the text; in that case the rule will fit the new text width). The `{0.4pt}` is the default height of rule.

As [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) rightfully points out in the comments this does introduce `\baselineskip` and `\parskip`, whereas `\hrule` does not. So be aware that paragraphs will be started after those rules.

Comment: note that `\rule` will by default be indented by the paragraph indentation, so a `\textwidth` rule will stick in to the right margin.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle would prefixing the command with `\noindent` solve that problem?

Comment: yes, but that isn't what you told the OP to do. (there are other differences too, `\rule` will introduce `\baselineskip` and `\parskip` vertical space which is not generated by `\hrule` which does not start a paragraph, so replacing `\hrule` by `\rule` may introduce additional changes. Perhaps that's OK but just saying "simply replace" is rather misleading.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the feedback! I have updated my answer accordingly.